# How to wrap class that passes unmanaged class in constructor?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, wrapper, unmanaged, managed

I am trying to understand C++/CLI so I can create Wrapper classes for C++ code. My problem is that I have a class which stores a pointer to a parent object of that class, therefore I need to pass it into the class.

Below is an example, but the full class has more functions and stores extra data.

```
class A
{
private:
    A* parent;

public:
    A(A* Parent)
    {
        parent = Parent;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        delete parent;
    }

    A* GetParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

My current idea is to have a non-public constructor so that you can construct a managed class with the unmanaged one without it being accessible outside the class.

```
public ref class ManagedA
{
    A* unmanaged;

    ManagedA(A* unmanaged)
    {
        this->unmanaged = unmanaged;
    }

public:
    ManagedA(ManagedA^ Parent)
    {
        unmanaged = new A(Parent->unmanaged);
    }

    ~ManagedA()
    {
        delete unmanaged;
        unmanaged = NULL;
    }

    ManagedA^ GetParent()
    {
        return gcnew ManagedA(unmanaged->GetParent());
    }
}
```

While this works for functions inside the class, I still have issues if I want to create an object or if I have a function that needs the unmanaged class to be passed in.

Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 2):

```
ManagedA^ GetParent()
{
    return gcnew ManagedA(unmanaged->GetParent());
}
```

You are shooting your leg off with code like this, it is *very* dangerous.  Problem is, you are creating multiple ManagedA objects that refer to the exact same A*.  As soon as *one* of them gets destroyed, all the other ManagedA objects now have a dangling pointer.  That's almost guaranteed to cause memory corruption.

The solution is very simple, just store the parent reference in the constructor:

```
public ref class ManagedA {
private:
    A* unmanaged;
    ManagedA^ parent;
public:
    ManagedA(ManagedA^ Parent) : parent(Parent) {
        A* unmanagedParent = Parent == nullptr ? nullptr : Parent->unmanaged;
        unmanaged = new A(unmanagedParent);
    }
    ManagedA^ GetParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    ~ManagedA() {
        this->!ManagedA();
        unmanaged = NULL;
    }
    !ManagedA() {
        delete unmanaged;
    }
};
```

Note the added nullptr check in the constructor, the only sane way I could see how the very first A* could ever get created.

That was the easy case, the exact same object identity problem occurs when you ever need to map an A* back to a ManagedA^.  First check if this is *really* needed, the client code is expected to only ever manipulate ManagedA objects.  When necessary, you'll need to create an lookup table so you can reliably find the corresponding ManagedA^ back.  That requires a static `Dictionary<IntPtr, ManagedA^>`.  Add objects to the dictionary in the constructor, remove them in the finalizer.  Note that you forgot to include a finalizer, it is not optional.  I added it to the snippet.

Comment: Yeah adding nullptr was how the first object is supposed to be initialised, like the head of a linked list or the root of a tree.

Although I'm still struggling with the second part of my problem. What if I have another managed wrapper class, and I need to convert an A* object to a ManagedA^ object?

I've really written myself into a corner with this...

Comment: I described what you need to do.  I'm still not buying it, where does the A* come from?  You'll never get it from the client code that uses your wrapper, it is completely unaware that an A* exists.

Comment: Best way I can answer that is that A* is like a hierarchy tree, where each node has one parent and many children, so that when it's created, the first one has a parent of nullptr and then the next one created is added to the first as a child.

Comment: The problem is that I also have a class that has a function which returns an A* object, so the wrapper should return the ManagedA^ instead. So how do I convert that A* into a ManagedA^ in that wrapper class?

Comment: Don't omit that from the question.  But, clearly, you will need that Dictionary.